# Strongly-Typed ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This code fails to actually save any changes:

```
//
// POST: /SomeType/Edit/5

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Edit(Guid id, SomeType Model)
{
    db.AttachTo(Model.GetType().Name, Model);
    db.ApplyPropertyChanges(Model.EntityKey.EntitySetName, Model);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

ASP.NET MVC creates the object Model as a Department type EntityObject with an EntityState value of **Detached**.

After using the *AttachTo* method, its EntityState becomes **Unchanged**.

[MSDN on Attaching Objects (Entity Framework)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271.aspx)

> Objects are attached to the object
>   context in an **Unchanged** state.

Because of its **Unchanged** state, the method *ApplyPropertyChanges* does nothing.

I want it to instead have state **Modified**.

[MSDN on EntityState Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entitystate.aspx)

> **Detached**
>   The object exists but it is not being tracked by Object
>   Services. An entity is in this state
>   immediately after it has been created
>   and before it is added to the object
>   context. An entity is also in this
>   state after it has been removed from
>   the context by calling the Detach
>   method or if it is loaded using a
>   NoTrackingMergeOption.
>
> **Unchanged**
>   The object has not been modified since it was loaded into
>   the context or since the last time
>   that the SaveChanges method was
>   called.
>
> **Modified**
>   The object is changed but the SaveChanges method has not
>   been called.

I cannot explicitly set an EntityObject's EntityState property to **Modified**.  It is read only.

Is it just impossible to have strongly-typed MVC controllers with EntityObjects?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/922402/strongly-typed-asp-net-mvc-with-ado-net-entity-framework

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to get the ObjectStateManager from your ObjectContext. With the ObjectStateManager, you can explicitly set the state for your object without needing to make a call to the database:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Edit(Guid id, SomeType Model)
{
    db.AttachTo(Model.GetType().Name, Model);

    ObjectStateManager stateMgr = db.ObjectStateManager;
    ObjectStateEntry stateEntry = stateMgr.GetObjectStateEntry(model);
    stateEntry.SetModified(); // Make sure the entity is marked as modified
    //db.ApplyPropertyChanges(Model.EntityKey.EntitySetName, Model);

    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The ObjectStateEntry also allows you to apply finer-grained state change data via the SetModifiedProperty. If you call SetModified, EF will treat the entire entity as modified, and persist every property to the data store. With SetModifiedProperty, EF can optimize the queries and only involve the properties that have actually changed. Using SetModifiedProperty is obviously more complex, as you usually need to know the original value of each property.

I hope this helps. ObjectStateManager is a powerful little tool in the EF toolbox, and can help improve EF v1.0's otherwise morbid performance and efficiency.

Comment: SetModifiedProperty works as expected.  But, SetModified doesn't seem to treat the entire entity as modified.  Rather than "persist every property to the data store", it persists none.

Comment: Thats a bit odd...there may be something else that needs to be done...but that sounds like a bug somewhere.

Comment: Great answer and new ground for me regarding ObjectContext, so thanks for the knowledge. I recently had a similar issue that I solved by morphing the OC into a DbContext temporarily: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33714849/objectcontext-with-entity-framework-6-inserting-duplicates-on-existing-related-e

Answer (score 3):

I found none of the above seemed to work for me, but the MSDN guide example did which is where you get the original item from the context, and then attach the updated item.

Second example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896248.aspx#Mtps_DropDownFilterText

```
private static void ApplyItemUpdates(SalesOrderDetail updatedItem){
// Define an ObjectStateEntry and EntityKey for the current object.
EntityKey key;
object originalItem;

using (AdventureWorksEntities advWorksContext =
    new AdventureWorksEntities())
{
    try
    {
        // Create the detached object's entity key.
        key = advWorksContext.CreateEntityKey("SalesOrderDetail", updatedItem);

        // Get the original item based on the entity key from the context
        // or from the database.
        if (advWorksContext.TryGetObjectByKey(key, out originalItem))
        {
            // Call the ApplyPropertyChanges method to apply changes
            // from the updated item to the original version.
            advWorksContext.ApplyPropertyChanges(
                key.EntitySetName, updatedItem);
        }

        advWorksContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
//
// POST: /SomeType/Edit/5

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Edit(Guid id, SomeType Model)
{
    Model.EntityKey = (from SomeType s in db.SomeType
                       where s.Id == id
                       select s).FirstOrDefault().EntityKey;
    db.ApplyPropertyChanges(Model.EntityKey.EntitySetName, Model);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

But is there a way without querying the database?

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you add one line:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Edit(Guid id, SomeType Model)
{
    db.AttachTo(Model.GetType().Name, Model);
    Model.SomeProperty = Model.SomeProperty; // This looks hacky... =(
    db.ApplyPropertyChanges(Model.EntityKey.EntitySetName, Model);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Does the state change?

Comment: I tried Model.Id = Model.Id but that caused an exception because that particular field is protected by the Entity Framework.  I didn't try any others.

Answer (score 1):

I have this working, but what iam not able to get at is the parent entity of SalesOrderDetail
How can i get at it?

SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderHead is null and also entityreference is null.
My edit routine has access to the id of SalesOrderDetail only.

Thanks
Sri

Comment: Try the "Ask Question" link to start a new Question.  Your issue will get more attention.